# Difference between union and intersection between two topologies.

Tags: general-topology

I was motivated by my question that [Find the interior and closure of these sets(Intersection between two topological spaces)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626044/find-the-interior-and-closure-of-these-setsintersection-between-two-topological/3626070#3626070)

Let the set $X$ and there are two different topological spaces $(X, T_1)$ and $(X,T_2)$ on a set $X$

I'm curious about the  either open or closed sets on  $(X,T_1 \cup T_2)$ and  $(X,T_1 \cap T_2)$ respectively.

So I made my conclusion that the form of those like below.

- $(X,T_1 \cup T_2)$ case (Say $T_1 \cup T_2$ is topological space)

$(1)$ Open set $G$ on the $T_1 \cup T_2$ $\iff$ $G$ is a open set on $T_1$ **or** $T_2$

Hence we can knew the all the open sets in $T_1$ and $T_2$ are sub-basis of the $(X,T_1 \cup T_2)$.

$(2)$ Closed set $F$ on the $T_1 \cup T_2$ $\iff$ $F$ is a closed set on $T_1$ **or** $T_2$

- $(X,T_1 \cap T_2)$ case

$(3)$ Open set $G$ on the $T_1 \cap T_2$ $\iff$ $G$ is a open set simultaneously on $T_1$ **and** $T_2$

$(4)$ Closed set $F$ on the $T_1 \cap T_2$ $\iff$ $F$ is a closed set simultaneously on $T_1$ **and** $T_2$

So my question is Are my conclusions $(1)$~$(4)$ correct? I have a little confidence my guess is right.

Any advice and answer always welcome.

p.s.) When you watch my post linked above, though my guess,I had a serious mistake that regarding the open set of the $T_1 \cup T_2$ for the $T_1 \cap T_2$.

Comment: I'm kind of confused by your third sentence. The union of two topologies is not necessarily a topology.

Comment: Err... @AlbertoTakase, I add more condition for union case

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, (3) and (4) are correct. At the moment (1) and (2) needs a patch because $T_1\cup T_2$ is not necessarily a topology. One idea is to consider the topology generated by $T_1\cup T_2$. If that patch is applied, then (1) and (2) are not correct.

EDIT: You propose the patch is to additionally assume $T_1\cup T_2$ is a topology.  This does occur 'in nature' when say $T_1$ is finer than $T_2$ for example. If the patch is applied, then (1) and (2) are correct.

Comment: Dear @Alberto Takase, Thanks for your comment. Though we add hypothesis that $T_1 \cup T_2$ is topology, We can't say (1) and (2) are  true. Is my understand is right? Plus Would you suggest the counterexample for me applying the patch?